# Returning value in a function to use in the same function repeatedly?

Tags: python, loops, return

I am working on a random walking generator for a turtle. The user inputs a row, column and probability value between 0 and 1. Within my main function, based on the value of the random number generated, the turtle will either turn or walk one step forward in the direction it is facing.

My issue is I need to repeat this function over and over again, (via a loop) but incorporating the values from the previous run of the function into the next one each time. Every attempt I have made ( via returning a tuple with the values and inputting those into every run of the function except for the first one) has resulted in the same value of the function being returned over and over.

```
   #Random Walk Generator#
    import random
    import sys


    def move_turtle(row, col, direct, turn_prob ):
        dir_list = ['right', 'down', 'left', 'up']
        random.random()
        if random.random()<=turn_prob:
            p= dir_list.index(direct)
            if p==0:
                p2=1
            elif p==1:
                p2=2
            elif p==2:
                p2= 3
            elif p==3:
                p2 =0
            d2= dir_list[p2]
            direct= d2

        else: 
            if direct == 'right':
                col= col+1
            if direct== 'down':
                row=row+1
            if direct =='left':
                col= col-1
            if direct== 'up':
                row= row-1

        rettup = (row,col,direct)

        return rettup


    N= input('Enter the integer number of rows => ')
    print N
    M= input('Enter the integer number of cols => ')
    print M
    p= input("Enter the turtle's turn probability (< 1.0) => ")
    print p

    seed_value = 10*M + N
    random.seed(seed_value)

    dir_list = ['right', 'down', 'left', 'up']
    rand_index = random.randint(0,3)
    d = dir_list[rand_index]

    print 'Initial direction:',d
    tup= move_turtle(M,N,d,p)

    for c in range(249):
        if c==0:
            move_turtle(M,N,d,p)
        else:
            move_turtle(tup[0],tup[1],tup[2],p)
        '''
        if R>= M or R<= -1 or C>=N or C<=-1:
            print 'After', c, 'time steps the turtle fell off the', D, 'in column',C
            '''
        if c==20 or c==40 or c==60 or c==80 or c==100 or c==120 or c==140 or c==180 or c==200 or c==220 or c==240 or c==250:
            print 'Time step',c,': position (',N/2,',',M/2,')direction',d
```

Comment: You are never changing the direction :) Put the `rand_index` and `d = dir_list[rand_index]` inside of your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not updating `tup` each time you call `move_turtle`. You're also calling `move_turtle` an extra time before the loop. That's not necessary because the loop performs the initial call when `c == 0`. So it should just be:

```
for c in range(249):
    if c == 0:
        tup = move_turle(M, N, d, p)
    else:
        tup = move_turtle(tup[0], tup[1], tup[2], p)
```

Comment: Yep. Seems to be running okay now. Thanks a bunch... was stuck on that for longer than I care to admit..